# Vim command line locks until opened file is closed

Tags: pdf, vim, cmd

I am trying to run latex in Vim (without leaving normal mode) in the following way:

1. Open the document.tex in vim
2. Compile the .tex file and turn it into a .pdf file. I do this with **:! pdflatex %**
3. View the pdf file. I do this with **:! %<.pdf**

This does show the pdf file (in ms edge) but the command line of Vim is locked: I can't do anything at all until I close the pdf file viewer. This is uncomfortable because, while I only need to compile from time to time, I want to keep the pdf open when correcting mistakes

Why doesn't **:! %<.pdf** work? Why does the cmd (I'm running this on Windows) "keep running" the command? How can I fix this?

Comment: I would say it *does* work, it just does something different than what you would like.

Comment: `:!<command>` *is* blocking, no matter what. Consider using `:help system()` instead or, better, use a standalone file watcher that handles the compiling and opening outside of Vim.